# r - remove from count if row below is contains a value

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I am trying to aggregate information based on a rolling count. However, there are instances where I want to not include a row in the aggregation row based on the row after it.

For example, I want the below to aggregate as 14 instead of 11. The type field indicates that row above should not be included.

```
data.frame(id = rep(123, 7),
           type = c(rep("d", 3), "c", rep("d", 3)),
           value = c(2, 4, 2, -2, 3, 5, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(id, type) %>% 
  mutate(count = seq(n()),
         count = ifelse(type == "c", count * -1, count)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(sum_field = case_when(count <= 4 & count >= 1 ~ value),
         sum_should_be = c(2, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(current = sum(sum_field, na.rm = T),
            desired = sum(sum_should_be, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example `dput()` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a leading variable. To keep in line with your code:

```
data.frame(id = rep(123,7), 
                type = c(rep('d', 3), 'c', rep('d',3)), 
                value = c(2,4,2,-2,3,5,2)) %>%
   mutate(lead_type = lead(type,1)) %>% 
   group_by(id, type, lead_type) %>% 
   mutate(count = seq(n()), 
          count = ifelse(type == 'd' & lead_type == 'd', count, 0)) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(sum_field = case_when(count <= 4 & count >= 1 ~ value)) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(current = sum(sum_field, na.rm = T))
```